# Sort Wordpress Search by Relevance

Tags: wordpress, search, relevance

I've created a pretty advanced search for a Wordpress site I'm working on atm. Allowing visitors to filter results by different taxonomies, sort them by date or custom fields as well as the normal free text search (which WP offers by default).

I've accomplished this using the `pre_get_posts` filter and by simply adding my stuff to the query, something like this: (note that I've left out some sanity checks and other code)

```
<?php
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'my_search');

function my_search ($qry) {
    # Include more post types
    $qry->set('post_type', array('foo', 'bar'));

    if ($_GET['myorder'] == 'price') {
        $qry->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
        $qry->set('meta_key', 'price');
        $qry->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
    else {
        $qry->set('orderby', 'date');
        $qry->set('order', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

Now I would like to add another way to sort the posts, namely by relevance. I understand this is a really common request and most solutions to the problem I've seen include using the Relevanssi plugin. Seeing as I've already written my own "plugin" (well, code at least) and have all my search forms and listings set up to use that, switching to Relevanssi won't be too easy at this point.

Sooo, I'd like to know if anyone knows of some (preferably) easy way to add this with the code I've already got?

As far as I understand, WP does its search using `LIKE` instead of `MATCH()` and that's why it doesn't even *have* a relevance score to sort on. If this is correct I assume I would have to write my own query altogether? How can I do this without messing up WP's pagination etc? Or could I add something like `$qry->set('WHERE', "MATCH(post_content) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance"); $qry->set('sortby', 'relevance')` do you reckon?

Comment: I know this plugin does a very good job: [Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/). Maybe it helps to fill the gaps.

Comment: Thanks, but if you read the whole question you'll see why I don't want to use that.

Comment: Yep, I got that, just thought maybe some useful stuff can be extracted from it. G'luck, great Q!

Comment: Relevanssi doesn't do well with non-English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I ended up using Relevanssi after all. But with quite a few modifications.

First of all, filtering on taxonomies was quite easy as this is built into Relevanssi, all I needed to do was change the names of my `<select>` elements to the taxonomy names + change the values to the slugs:

```
<select name="custom_taxonomy">
    <option value="some-term">Some term</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Second, to allow sorting by a custom field, I had to use the `relevanssi_hits_filter` filter. Unlike `pre_get_posts` or `relevanssi_modify_wp_query` (which Sheikh Heera kindly suggested), this filter gets passed the array of posts and *not* a WP_Query object. When I tried to use the WP_Query object the order simply refused to change. Here's basically how to do your own sort with `relevanssi_hits_filter`:

```
<?php
add_filter('relevanssi_hits_filter', 'h5b_hits_filter');

function h5b_hits_filter ($hits) {
    global $wp_query;

    if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['orderby']) and $wp_query->query_vars['orderby'] == 'price') {
        if (count($hits[0])) {
            usort($hits[0], 'h5b_sort_by_price');
        }
    }

    return $hits;
}

function h5b_sort_by_price ($a, $b) {
    $priceKey   = 'price';
    $aPrice     = get_post_meta($a->ID, $priceKey, true);
    $bPrice     = get_post_meta($b->ID, $priceKey, true);
    $aPrice     = $aPrice ? $aPrice : 10000000;
    $bPrice     = $bPrice ? $bPrice : 10000000;

    if ($aPrice == $bPrice) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($aPrice < $bPrice) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

This also helped with a previous problem I had in that posts that *lacked* the "price" key didn't show up in searches. Now they do, and the reason I give them a price of "10000000" is so that they show up *after* the ones that do have a price.

Finally, I also needed **empty searches** to work. According to the Relevanssi dev this is only supported in the Premium version, but I think I managed to work around it. First I forced WP to display the search page even if ?s was empty:

```
<?php
add_filter('request', 'h5b_allow_empty_search');

function h5b_allow_empty_search ($qryVars) {
    if (isset($_GET['s']) and empty($_GET['s'])) {
        $qryVars['s'] = ' ';
    }

    return $qryVars;
}
```

Second, I told Relevanssi to fetch *all* posts if ?s was empty, by default it won't fetch any posts at all. Unfortunately, in doing this the default behaviour with custom taxonomies stopped working (my code over wrote it) so I had to manually check for taxonomies in this code as well:

```
<?php
add_filter('relevanssi_hits_filter', 'h5b_allow_empty_search_filter');

function h5b_allow_empty_search_filter ($hits) {
    if (isset($_GET['s']) and empty($_GET['s']) and !count($hits[0])) {
        $taxQry = array('relation' => 'AND');

        if (!empty($_GET['custom_taxonomy'])) {
            $taxQry[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy', 
                'field' => 'slug', 
                'terms' => $_GET['custom_taxonomy']
            );
        }

        $args = array(
            'numberposts' => -1, 
            'post_type' => 'any'
        );

        if (count($taxQry) > 1) {
            $args['tax_query'] = $taxQry;
        }

        $hits[0] = get_posts($args);
    }

    return $hits;
}
```

And that's it. Everything seems to work and hopefully this will help someone who has similar requests in the future.

I really hope WP improves its ridiculous search in the future. Sorting by relevance should be something that's available in the world's most popular CMS imo.

Thanks @Sheikh Heera for pointing me in the right direction. I'm not sure who to give the right answer to though seeing as I really couldn't use the stuff you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use `Relevanssi` without any problem but need to use a `filter` hook, check [relevanssi_modify_wp_query](http://www.relevanssi.com/user-manual/filter-hooks/) for more details, check following code

```
function func_reli($qry){
    $qry->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'restaurant', 'products' ) );

    if ($_GET['myorder'] == 'price') {
        $qry->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
        $qry->set('meta_key', 'price');
        $qry->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
    else {
        $qry->set('orderby', 'date');
        $qry->set('order', 'DESC'); // <-- set (in your code 'add' is used)
    }
    return $qry; // <-- must return, in your code you didn't
}
add_filter('relevanssi_modify_wp_query', 'func_reli');
```

I've tested this code and just works fine. In this example I've used `'restaurant'` and `'products'` custom post types and search works really fine, just the relevant results. You can also use if `php 5.3+` is installed

```
add_filter('relevanssi_modify_wp_query', function($qry){
    // Same code
});
```

Also, if you use [Relevanssi](http://www.relevanssi.com/) plugin, you can use it's setup page to set `post_type` instead of using this (`$qry->set( 'post_type', array(...) )`) in your `functions.php` file.

### Scree shot given below

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a really good answer, I will try Relevanssi and come back.

Comment: Ok, this looked promising but for some reason it's not working. I seem to be able to sort by date, but trying to sort by my custom field results in the same order as relevance (or nothing set). No idea why. It seems most people use the `relevanssi_hits_filter` filter for adding their own sort, but that looks much more complicated (can't use the WPQuery object but rather you have to sort an array yourself). Ideas?

Comment: I also need it to work with empty searches as well as filtering by custom taxonomies. Doesn't seem to be as easy as this reply suggests.

Comment: Ok I ended up using Relevanssi after all but with a different hook and completely different code (the `relevanssi_hits_filter` I mentioned before). I had to `usort()` the array of posts myself rather than rely on WP's "orderby" setting. It works though.

Comment: Glad to know that, would you mind to share it with community ?

Answer (score 3):

Just found out that WP already has this in core.

In https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/, look at the "orderby" => "relevance" parameter.

> Order by search terms in the following order: First, whether the
> entire sentence is  matched. Second, if all the search terms are
> within the titles. Third, if any of the search terms appear in the
> titles. And, fourth, if the full sentence appears in the contents.

Comment: This should be the right answer. Thanks for sharng it!